# Strange hyphenation behaviour - partly due to multirow v2.1

Tags: hyphenation, multirow

I'm not sure about a matching example in English, but in the following case, I can't understand hyphenation behaviour at all.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Based on the class scrreprt by "KOMA-Script", whatever that means. If that doesn't help, please try \documentclass{scrreprt} or one of the usual.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\hyphenation{Kom-mu-ni-zier-bar-keit} % didn't work in the first place...
\hyphenation{Fahr-gast-be-fra-gung} % same here...

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{6em}|x|P{8em}|}
\hline
\hspace{0pt}Kommuni\-zier\-barkeit & Verständlichkeit und Vermittelbarkeit des Programms für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste & \hspace{0pt}Mitarbeiterbefragung, Fahrgastbefragung, teilnehmender Beobachter \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing "Fahrgastbefragung" to "Fahrgast\-befragung" didn't help much, as you can see.

[image]

It is not until using the ugly "Fahrgast-\newline befragung" that the remaining space in that second line is being used as desired.

[image]

Is there a more elegant way than this workaround? Why didn't my first two attempts succeed?

Ulrike Fischer's suggestion already helped for the situation above (thank you!). Why aren't there line breaks after commas when using multirow (version 2.1, see below)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Based on the class scrreprt by "KOMA-Script", whatever that means. If that doesn't help, please try \documentclass{scrreprt} or one of the usual.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\hyphenation{Kom-mu-ni-zier-bar-keit} % didn't work in the first place...
\hyphenation{Fahr-gast-be-fra-gung} % same here...

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{6em}|x|P{7em}|}
\hline
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Zuverlässigkeit, Funktionalität} & Reibungsloser Ablauf bei wiederholter Anwendung & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Mitarbeiterbefragung, Fahrgastbefragung, teilnehmender Beobachter}\\
& Praktische Umsetzbarkeit des Betriebsprogramms & \\
& Reibungsloses Einführen und Aufheben des Betriebsprogramms & \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\raggedright` doesn't care about large white spaces. Use `\RaggedRight` from the ragged2e package.

Comment: That already helped for other tabulars, thank you! But when using multirow, lines still won't break after the commas. Why might that be?

Comment: Do you use multirow version 2.1?

Comment: Apparently not. I'll delete my comment. You might want to mention this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `multirow` documentation version 2.1.:

> Just before *text* is expanded, the `\multirowsetup` macro is expanded 
>   to set up any special environment. Initially, `\multirowsetup` contains just
>   `\raggedright`. It may be redefined with `\renewcommand`.

So you can use

```
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\RaggedRight}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}[2016/10/11]
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\RaggedRight}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{6em}|x|P{7em}|}
\hline
  \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Zuverlässigkeit, Funk"-tionalität} 
    & Reibungsloser Ablauf bei wiederholter Anwendung 
    & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Mitarbeiterbefragung, Fahrgastbefragung, teilnehmender Beobachter}\\
& Praktische Umsetzbarkeit des Betriebsprogramms 
  & \\
& Reibungsloses Einführen und Aufheben des Betriebsprogramms 
  & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```